# Why am I getting error when using expo-facebook login in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook, expo, expo-go

I have a managed workflow expo project (SDK 44) and I tried to follow the documentation to implement the solution. These are the steps I took:

- Register to Facebook Developer
- Install expo-facebook
- Fetch key hash for android app and add it on Facebook
- Added "host.exp.Exponent" as Bundle ID on Facebook
- Added the sample code from the docs

[image]

[image]

```
async function logIn() {
  try {
    await Facebook.initializeAsync({
      appId: '<APP_ID>',
    });
    const { type, token, expirationDate, permissions, declinedPermissions } =
      await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
        permissions: ['public_profile'],
      });
    if (type === 'success') {
      // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
      const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
      Alert.alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
    } else {
      // type === 'cancel'
    }
  } catch ({ message }) {
    alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
  }
}
```

Then it redirects me to my App's Facebook page, where I can see my app details, and image.

After I add my Facebook credentials I get the following error:

> Webpage not available The webpage at
> fbconnect://cct.host.exp.exponent#granted_scopes=public_profile&denied_scopes=&signed_request=VhUPKkgri83xZuKbpsop5XFf4sLD72HeFHn5mgHKtTY.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&graph_domain=facebook&access_token=EAAPYJXwv3ysBAN0gNls0mMoJ9NoZBbRvOQYMyaAqwlfHL7vcZA1ZAq4jPJsZBZCZCc5qG6sWSBY5w7Xc4ZArScfi6bvIA7brKz4S4AtWUDLyw71hfmnHYckdi1fLSqRLZBxfVfEGDPz9W5ZBFxHsScpoFXI4EzTwis11hiD58yLXubhnn5JZBm08Fje7FhI0DbTBZA0AZAFgObcLC0s75ZCTQ7SaZAPKLRT3W0kAiAAi2eolUntXy6gslYKEYY&data_access_expiration_time=1651743691&expires_in=5182128&state=%7B%220_auth_logger_id%22%3A%228315c2f8-8e7f-42c5-8496-5d45fd1f1f25%22%2C%223_method%22%3A%22custom_tab%22%2C%227_challenge%22%3A%22b4as3835lr367tdn0m0n%22%7D
> could not be loaded because:
>
> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

[image]

What am I doing wrong? :/

EDIT:

Reading the documentation I found this:

> Add the field facebookScheme with your Facebook login redirect URL
> scheme found on the Facebook Developer website under "4. Configure
> Your info.plist." It should look like "fb123456". If you do not do
> this, Facebook will not be able to redirect to your app after logging
> in.

I added this tree line to my app.json under expo, but still getting redirect error:

"facebookScheme":"fb10820804390*****",
"facebookAppId":"1082080439******",
"facebookDisplayName":"E-Kisállatkönyv"

Comment: Is your Facebook login app live?

Comment: It was in "development" mode, just changed it to live mode to test, but I get the same error. Also I am trying on a physical device.

Comment: May be the hash key incorrent

Comment: I triple checked that, should be all good :((

Comment: Can you please create a demo app and try to integrate Facebook login without the hash key and bundle id in the developer account?

Comment: Then I get the following error in the Facebook app after pressing the log in button: "To use this URL you have to add a valid native platform to your application"